# Define variables in a column

Tags: spacing

I am having trouble aligning/setting up my variable definitions in my paper. I have attached a picture of my current results. [image]

So this is a two column paper and the results I have shown go in one column. Notice that the spacings are not aligned. The latex code that I have written is the following

[image]

Any help in getting everything lined up correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Andrew

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please add the code so that we can copy paste and test. Make it compilable too (starting from `\documentclass{}...` and ending at `\end{document}`.  You can use a `tabular` for this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\noindent
where for (1)--(4)
\begin{tabbing}
    \hspace{2cm} \= \hspace{3cm} \kill
    $P(t),Q(t)$ \> current time measure.....\\
    $V(t),F(t)$ \> current time measure.....\\
\end{tabbing}
or alternatively\par\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}l<{$}l}
    P(t),Q(t) & current time measure.....\\
    V(t),F(t) & current time measure.....\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you use some package like `nomencl` or `glossaries` for things like this.